# Как считывать определенную информацию из текстового файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно сделать программу-тест, которая бы брала из текстового файла вопросы(не все сразу, по одному) и варианты ответа к ним и выводила бы всё это в консоль, а затем бы записывала в другой текстовый файл и  оценивала правильность ответов. Я не знаю, как сделать такое выборочное сканирование файла.

```
test = open('questions.txt', 'r')
for line in test:
    print (line) # тут должно быть условие
```

ТЗ: Создайте программу, которая берет вопросы и варианты ответов из текстового файла и выводит их пользователю. Затем программа должна сравнивать ответы с правильными вариантами и выставлять оценку (количество вопросов – 10).

Comment: Считывать построчно файл (цикл for может построчно считывать файлы), например до какого-нибудь разделителя. Конкретизируйте вопрос, шаблон файла приветствуется, ваша попытка в коде тоже

Comment: test = open('questions.txt', 'r')
for line in test: print (line) 
  #  тут должно быть условие которое бы проверяло, является ли строка файла вопросом или нет. Если да, то выводится вопрос и все варианты ответа к нему. я не знаю, как организовать процесс проверки на вопрос и вывода его в консоль, если строка является вопросом.

Comment: Я давно не программировал, извините, если туплю.

Comment: Уже лучше (вы показали кусочек кода и кое-что из ТЗ), но такое нужно в вопросе писать (кнопка `править`). Я правильно понимаю, что `является ли строка файла вопросом или нет` вопрос может быть только на одной строке и всегда заканчивается символом вопроса `?`?

Comment: Добавил текст ТЗ в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Это всё, конечно, костыльно выглядит, но вот вариант.

В файл с вопросами записываете инфу в таком виде:

```
Вопрос1@ответ1@ответ2@ответ3@ответ4
Вопрос2@ответ1@ответ2@ответ3@ответ4
Вопрос3@ответ1@ответ2@ответ3@ответ4
```

То есть каждый новый вопрос с новой строки и через собачку `@` без пробелов варианты ответов.

Потом несколько извращенный код.

```
path_1 = 'Путь к файлу с вопросами.txt' #Заменить на пути к файлам
path_2 = 'Путь к файлу для ответов.txt'

f2 = open(path_2, 'a')

with open(path_1, "r") as f:
    for string in f.readlines():
        question = string.split('@')[0]
        answer_1 = string.split('@')[1]
        answer_2 = string.split('@')[2]
        answer_3 = string.split('@')[3]
        answer_4 = string.split('@')[4]

        print("\n{}\n".format(question))
        print("Вариант 1: {}".format(answer_1))
        print("Вариант 2: {}".format(answer_2))
        print("Вариант 3: {}".format(answer_3))
        print("Вариант 4: {}".format(answer_4))

        variants = {'1' : answer_1, '2' : answer_2, '3' : answer_3, '4' : answer_4}

        ans = input('\nВведите номер варианта ответа и нажмите Enter: ')
        f2.write("{}\n{}\n\n".format(question, variants[ans]))

f2.close()
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую)

Comment: Лучше так: `question, answer_1, answer_2, answer_3, answer_4 = string.split('@')`

Comment: Да, если не преследовать целью наглядность кода, то так лучше.